# How to get only value from an object array without column name and brackets?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Here is the code**

```
var obj = {!!json_encode($assets_name)!!}

Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {

console.log(key, obj[key]);

});
```

//Actual Result

[image]

// **Trying to Get**

Is there a way to get this result?

```
Keyboard,Mouse,Spoons,Paper,Keyboard
```

Comment: Looks like your `obj` is actually an array of objects.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/from-an-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `Object.keys` use [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) which will return a array of the value. Then you can use `join(',')` which will return a string joined by `comma`